# Cannot access class 'com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference'

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an Android project and I'm using Firebase as my backend. I've created a module that will handle all Firestore related work. In this module, I created this class:

```kotlin
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference
import java.util.*

data class SurveyDto(
        var id: String = "",
        var name: String = "",
        var type: String = "",
        var creationDate: Date = Date(),
        var createdBy: DocumentReference? = null,
        var current: Boolean = true,
        var sections: List<SectionDto> = listOf()
)
```

In my main Module I created a Mapper class that will be in charge of converting my `SurveyDto` object into a `Survey` object (mapping logic was omitted for simplicity):

```kotlin
class SectionDtoMapper: DomainMapper<SectionDto, Section> {

    private val questionDtoMapper = QuestionDtoMapper()

    override fun mapToDomainModel(model: SectionDto): Section {
        return Section()
    }

    override fun mapFromDomainModel(domainModel: Section): SectionDto {
        return SectionDto()
    }

}
```

The problem is that, if I try running the app, it shows this runtime exception at `return SectionDto()`:

> Cannot access class 'com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

If I remove the `var createdBy: DocumentReference? = null` attribute from my `SurveyDto` class, or if I remove the `return SectionDto()` code, the app runs just fine.

I'm importing this to my firebase module:

```
implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.8.0")
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx"

// Some other firebase and non firebase imports
```

On my main module, i'm importing:

```
implementation platform(rootProject.ext.firebase.bom)
implementation project(':libraries:firebase_api')

// Some other firebase and non firebase imports
```

Please keep in mind that I have a lot of objects that import `DocumentReference`, but they're all written in Java... Don't know if this could be related!

Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So, I solved my problem adding manually an empty constructor for my data class:

```kotlin
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference
import java.util.*

data class SurveyDto(
        var id: String,
        var name: String,
        var type: String,
        var creationDate: Date,
        var createdBy: DocumentReference?,
        var current: Boolean,
        var sections: List<SectionDto>
) {
    constructor() : this(
        id = "",
        name = "",
        type = "",
        creationDate = Date(),
        createdBy = null,
        current = true,
        sections = listOf()
    )
}
```

I have no idea why this fixed my problem... I always thought that assigning a default value for each field would be the same as creating a secondary constructor